# Store DB Design

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to design my database to where the transaction Table(TransactionId(PK), ItemListNoId(FK), StoreId(FK), Date, EmployeeId(FK)) can access a list of products from the ItemList Table(ItemListNo(PK), UPC(FK)), however; I will run into an issue of not being able to input the an entry with the same ItemNoList number. All of the column types are of type int.

I can't quite figure out a way around this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Transaction` doesn't reference `ItemList` in your descriptions - are you planning on adding a column to `Transaction` referencing `ItemList.ItemListNo`?

Comment: OK, but I'm still not sure of what you're asking. Is the problem that you can't relate more than one ItemListNo for each Transaction, that you can't add more than one ItemListNo with the same ID, you can't have more than one Transaction with the same ID, or something else?

Comment: The problem is that I can't have more than one ItemListNo with same ID in the ItemList table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating another column in the `ItemList` table, call it something else (ItemID for example). Set it as `INT NOT NULL IDENTITY`, and change the primary key to that instead of ItemListNo.

Comment: I won't be able to access the table's data via the ItemListNo column because it's not a PK anymore.

Comment: Well you either want it as a PK, or you want to insert duplicate values into that column - one or the other!